# How to send to client dictionary which contains utf characters with simplejson?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, simplejson

I have in dictionary under key "verb" string which contains non ascii characters (utf-8).
I want to send to client that dictionary (I am using Tornado i Python 2.7.2 and simplejson).
I am trying like

```
result = {"verb" : "Želeći"}
self.write(simplejson.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)) # tried also with utf-8 encoding parameter passed 
self.flush()
```

but always get error **utf8 codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 0**

How to send to client dictionary which contains utf characters with simplejson ?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> result = {"verb" : "Želeći"}
>>> simplejson.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)
u'{"verb": "\u017dele\u0107i"}'
```

I'm using python 2.7.4

Answer (score 0):

You have data that is **not** UTF-8 encoded.

JSON strings are really Unicode strings, but you are giving it a byte string instead. Decode your data manually first instead of having the `json` module do it for you, wrongly.

Judging by the error code, you have windows-1252 (cp1252) encoded data instead, so the following will work:

```
result['verb'] = result['verb'].decode('cp1252')
simplejson.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False).encode('UTF8')
```

It could also be windows-1250; both 1250 and 1252 encode the `Ž` character (Unicode codepoint U+017D, LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON) to hex 8E.